# Does Android Version > 7 support LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: android, c++

I'm trying to preload a .so file that I've created, to a native app. But whenever I open the app, it crashes.

I do have root access. And my setenforce is permessive

This is what i've used

LD_PRELOAD=/path/mylib.so /path/native_app &

Since ldd is'nt supported in Android,

I used:

strings /path/to/app | grep ^lib

My lib wasn't listed there.

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed reply. LD_PRELOAD works on android version > 7. I tested in Nougat.